# How (and why) is this colon in python functionality

Tags: python

I am not sure what to call this syntax and therefore I am not able to search for anything about why it exists. (snippet works in python v3.7.3 and v3.6.5)

```
>>> RandomStuff: x = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> x = 1
>>> x
1
>>> RandomStuff: x = 2
>>> x
1
>>>
```

Comment: These are called type hints: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: Search for `":"` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html).

Comment: oh, right. I am aware of type hints but have mostly seen it in the form of `d : int = 5`

Comment: I wasn't used to seeing a variable as type hint and got confused. Thanks